# Почему vk.com перенаправляет на m.vk.com

Tags: python, вконтакте, requests

Почему    `requests.get('https://vk.com').url` возвращает 'https://m.vk.com/'? Как сделать, чтобы возвращалась полная версия сайта?

Comment: Скорее всего, анализирует заголовок User-Agent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VK -умный сайт, и более того, он слишком умный сайт, чтобы работать, как вы хотите. При зарпосе он смотрит, какой у вас юзер-агент, и если он не от дефолтный, то добро пожаловать в мобильную версию.

Чтобы оно заработало так, как вы хотите, вам нужно указать при запросе этот самый юзер-агент:

```
import requests
headers = {
    'User-Agent': % YOUR USER-AGENT %
    # 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0'
}
url = 'https://vk.com'
requests.get(url, headers=headers).url
# 'https://vk.com/'
```

Нужный агент вы можете взять [отсюда](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/), либо узнать свой [здесь](https://%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82.%D1%80%D1%84/) (у меня, например, это `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0`).